# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while calling a dll from java

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

I have a java programm which needs a .jar and a .dll file. If running the java programm from command line it works. Running it out of eclipse I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.osisoft.rdsa.RDSAChannel.GetDASVersion(J)S

at com.osisoft.rdsa.RDSAChannel.GetDASVersion(Native Method)
at com.osisoft.rdsa.RDSAChannel.<init>(RDSAChannel.java:58)
at com.osisoft.rdsa.NativeRDSA.create(NativeRDSA.java:185)
at com.osisoft.rdsa.NativeRDSA.create(NativeRDSA.java:127)
at com.osisoft.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:75)
at com.osisoft.jdbc.DriverExtension.connect(DriverExtension.java:121)
at com.osisoft.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at testclients.jtesterbase.JTesterBase.connect(JTesterBase.java:417)
at testclients.jtesterbase.JTesterBase.init(JTesterBase.java:182)
at testclients.jtesterbase.JTesterBase.main(JTesterBase.java:552)
```

what is the problem?

The .dll file is in `C:\Windows\system\32\RDSAWrapper64.dll`, so it has already be in the java.lang search path.

What environment changes between executing on console and executing in eclipse?

Has somebody some tips. I tried to fix it for hours.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It is obvious that the library is found and loaded otherwise you'd get something like: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /path/to/mylib.dll: Can't find dependent libraries. So your problem is that the method signature in the DLL does not match the Java method signature. Either your DLL is not up to date OR the Java code is not up to date. Running from command line could eventually use an old JAR while the Eclipse application uses the latest and greatest.

Comment: Thanks for your help
I build the .jar file myself. There exists just one version of it. So im absoltuely sure they use the same one.

Comment: Can it be that the eclipse compiler does something different than the javac? It's the only caue which I can think about at the moment.

Comment: I also have created the .dll file. Therefore it is a very strange behaviour

Comment: Does somebody has another tip what could be wrong?

Comment: Does [dependency walker](http://dependencywalker.com) show the exported function signature that you expect?  The error indicates that the JVM can't find the corresponding native method for the signature it is providing in the error message.